# How would you solve this complex derivative?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$$\omega = \log(z-z_0)$$

First of all, I tried to show that if you write $\omega$ as $\omega = \log(r-r_0) + \imath(\theta + \theta_0) + 4n\pi $, that you could use the Cauchy-Riemann conditions to show that the function's derivative exists.

Thus,

$$ \omega = \underbrace{\log(r-r_0)}_u + \imath\underbrace{(\theta + \theta_0) + 4n\pi}_v $$

such that

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$

The problem is that I can't seem to solve the right hand side of the Cauchy-Riemann Conditions and because of that I'm now having doubts if my approach is even correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to compute $\omega'$?

If you fix any continuous branch of the complex logarithm, $f(z) = \log z$, then $f'(z) = 1/z$. This follows for example from the complex variant of the inverse function theorem, or the following computation (fill in the details)

$$
f'(z) = \lim_{w \to z} \frac{\log(w) - \log(z)}{w-z} = \lim_{w' \to z'} \frac{w' - z'}{e^{w} - e^{z'}} = \frac1{e^{z'}} = \frac1z.
$$
(For a fixed branch, locally $\log$ is the inverse of $\exp$, and by continuity of $\log$, it follows that $w'\to z'$.)

I.e., $\omega' = \dfrac{1}{z-z_0}$.

Of course, you need to delete a curve from $z_0$ to $\infty$ in the domain of definition of $\omega$.

Comment: Yes I do want to compute for $\omega'$, but the thing is I want to show correctly that the derivative exists at the point $z-z_0$ that's why I'm trying to show that the Cauchy-Riemann conditions works for the functions $u$ and $v$.

But I do know that $\omega' = \frac{1}{z-z_0}$

Comment: @Aldon I showed you a way to just that. A computation via Cauchy-Riemann is also possible, but will require a lot of tedious calculations.

Comment: Oh oh yeah I just noticed it sorry.